# Mathematical induction on $ [R(\cos(t) + i\sin(t) )]^n = R^n(\cos(nt) + i\sin(nt)) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Using Mathematical Induction, where $n$ is a positive integer, prove:

$$ [R( \cos(t) + i\sin(t) )]^n = R^n(\cos(nt) + i\sin(nt)) $$

I am not entirely aware of what $i\sin(x)$ would be, or what value $R$ is suppose to hold.

Comment: Do you really have to use induction for this?  It's an immediate consequence of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: If you're 'not entirely aware' of what $i\sin(t)$ would be,then I'm wondering where you came across this. The general notion is that $R$ is an arbitrary value; this is proving how powers of complex numbers work.  (As for the induction itself, it's relatively straightforward using the addition formulas for sine and cosine and a little bit of complex math - just expand out $(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))\times(\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt))$ for the induction step on one side, and write out $\cos((n+1)x)$ and $\sin((n+1)x)$ in terms of $\cos(nx), \cos(x), \sin(nx) and \sin(x)$ using the addition formulas on the other.

Comment: The leading coefficient is obvious. Thus it is sufficient to show (cos(t)+isin(t))^n=cos(nt)+isin(nt)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I was under the impression that isin(x) was a special function like arcsin(x); not the product of the imaginary number and sin(x). And I also was not sure if R was suppose to be some known constant, such as e. Thank you for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

The base case is obvious. For the inductive step :

$$
\left(R(\cos t+ i\sin t) \right)^{n+1}=\left(R(\cos t+ i\sin t) \right)^{n}\left(R(\cos t+ i\sin t) \right)=$$ $$=R^{n+1}\left((\cos nt+ i\sin nt)(\cos t+ i\sin t) \right)=
$$
$$
R^{n+1}\left(\cos nt\cos t+i\cos nt \sin t +i \sin nt \cos t -\sin nt \sin t \right)=R^{n+1}\left(\cos (nt+t)+i\sin (nt+t) \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

As for more information about $i\sin(x)$, you are referred to the nature of a complex number. However, you need somehow to know a bit about polar coordinates in the plane( Argand Plane). Let $n=1$, so the equality holds. If $n=k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and the statments holds for $k$ then $$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^{k+1}=[\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)][\cos(x)+i\sin(x)]=\cos(kx+x)+i\sin(kx+x)$$ which shows that your claim is true for $k+1$. If $n=k\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}$ then assume you have $k=-n$ which is a positive integer. Of course we have it for $n=0$. Just check this case mutually.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}[R( \cos(t) + i\sin(t) )]^{n+1} &= [R( \cos(t) + i\sin(t) )]^{n}[R( \cos(t) + i\sin(t) )] \\
&= [R^n(\cos(nt) + i\sin(nt))] [R( \cos(t) + i\sin(t) )]
\\&= R^{n+1}\left[ \cos(nt)\cos(t)-\sin(nt)\sin(t)+i(\cos(nt)\sin(t)+\sin(nt)\cos(t) \right]\end{align}

Using trigonometric addition formula to complete the rest.

Comment: Why “double angle”? Maybe “addition formula”.

Comment: ah, thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is trivially true for $n=1$. The term $\iota$ or $i$ is just treated like a constant. Now, let us assume hypothetically that $[R(\cos t+\iota \sin t)^k=R^k[\cos(kt)+\iota \sin(kt)]$. Now, the inductive step $[R(\cos t +\iota \sin t)]^{k+1}=R^{k+1}[\cos(k+1)t+\iota \sin(k+1)t]$ can be proved using basic addition formulae for sine and cosine. Hence, the theorem is proved using induction. This is the standard De-Moivre's Theorem.